# MongoDB GridFS error: Duplicate element name 'filename'

Tags: c#, mongodb, nosql

I'm completely new to MongoDB, so perhaps this is something obvious. But Googling didn't work.

I set up a brand new MongoDB account, created a database named 'resizer-test' with accnt 'resizer' and password 'test'. I then uploaded an image named 'flames.jpg' using the web interface successfully.

I then tried to download the file from C# using the following code and the official C# driver (version 1.3.1)

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://resizer:test@staff.mongohq.com:10028/resizer-test";
this.db = MongoDatabase.Create(connectionString);
gridSettings = new MongoGridFSSettings();
grid = db.GetGridFS(gridSettings);
return grid.OpenRead("flames.jpg");
```

But immediately got this exception:

```
InvalidOperationException: Duplicate element name 'filename'.

 at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Add(BsonElement element) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Bson\ObjectModel\BsonDocument.cs:line 452
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Bson\ObjectModel\BsonDocument.cs:line 720
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument.ReadFrom(BsonReader bsonReader) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Bson\ObjectModel\BsonDocument.cs:line 393
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonReader bsonReader, Type nominalType, IBsonSerializationOptions options) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Bson\Serialization\BsonSerializer.cs:line 214
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoReplyMessage`1.ReadFrom(BsonBuffer buffer, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Internal\MongoReplyMessage.cs:line 94
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.ReceiveMessage[TDocument](BsonBinaryReaderSettings readerSettings, IBsonSerializationOptions serializationOptions) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Internal\MongoConnection.cs:line 383
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetReply(MongoConnection connection, MongoRequestMessage message) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 263
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.GetFirst() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 223
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursorEnumerator`1.MoveNext() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\Core\MongoCursorEnumerator.cs:line 126
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.Refresh() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs:line 447
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.get_Exists() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs:line 150
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSStream..ctor(MongoGridFSFileInfo fileInfo, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFSStream.cs:line 76
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.Open(FileMode mode, FileAccess access) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs:line 408
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFSFileInfo.OpenRead() in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFSFileInfo.cs:line 416
   at MongoDB.Driver.GridFS.MongoGridFS.OpenRead(String remoteFileName) in C:\work\10gen\mongodb\mongo-csharp-driver\Driver\GridFS\MongoGridFS.cs:line 696
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.MongoReader.MongoReaderPlugin.MongoVirtualFile.Open() in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Plugins\MongoReader\MongoReaderPlugin.cs:line 79
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.GetStreamFromSource(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean& disposeStream, String& path, Boolean& restoreStreamPosition) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 253
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.LoadImage(Object source, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean restoreStreamPos) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 135
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.BuildJob(ImageJob job) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 388
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(ImageJob job) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 371
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource, Boolean addFileExtension) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 357
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings, Boolean disposeSource) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 343
   at ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Build(Object source, Object dest, ResizeSettings settings) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\ImageBuilder.cs:line 330
   at ImageResizer.InterceptModule.<>c__DisplayClass2.<HandleRequest>b__1(Stream stream) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\InterceptModule.cs:line 266
   at ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCacheHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\resizer\Core\Plugins\Basic\NoCacheHandler.cs:line 28
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Guess what! The error message was legit.

MongoHQ.COM was attaching duplicate filename elements to the file during upload - it's a bug in their manual file managed interface.